# ¿ Como obtener la url del repositorio de git hub?

Tags: github, git-bash

Tengo un proyecto guardado en el repositorio de Git Hub, Necesito acceder al repositorio desde otra pc y asi poder subir los cambios. Entonces con Git Bash ¿Cómo hay que crear mi repositorio local apuntando al repositorio de git Hub para poder subir los cambios ? por que al hacer  git add . me tira este error:

fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: puedes descargar tu repo de la web configurar tu user y pass del github y hacer push con tus nuevos cambios

Comment: Gracias por responder! soy novato en git hub y bash. el proyecto ya lo descargué pulsando el botón verde CODE --> Download ZIP. de hecho creo que ahí mismo me muestra la url algo asi https://github.com/blabla/miProyecto.git si es que es esa, despues no se como seguir sus pasos desde Git Bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución era clonar el repositorio en mi ordenador. Después de hacer el `git add ..` al intentar hacer el `git commit -m 'aca va mi commit'`, Git Bash me solicitó el user email y el user name, indicando que tipee los siguientes comandos:

**git config --global user.email miEmail@gmail.com**

**git config --global user.name "mi nombre de usuario"**

y por último al hacer el `git push`, una ventana de git hub me pidió que le ingresara el email/username y el password.

Este video tutorial fue la solución:
[Clonar un repositorio de Git Hub en nuestro ordenador](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cZtiUMfa_M)

Answer (score 2):

Este es un ejemplo concreto para tu problema:

Lo primero que debes de hacer es descargar GIT:
https://git-scm.com/downloads

Lo instalas en tu pc.

Luego creas una carpeta llamadas por ejemplo "Repositorios" ahora para poder descargar el repositorio a tu carpeta local llamada "Repositorios" lo recomendable no es que descargues el .zip Sino que clones desde la consola de comandos del programa "git".

Para eso entonces haces algo parecido a esto:

Dentro de la carpeta repositorios ya con el programa instalado haces esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Haces click en "Git bash here"

Luego se abrira el Git. Como es tu primera vez deberas de configurar tu nombre y correo.

Para eso ejecutar los siguientes comandos:

1. #> git config --global user.name "no nombre"
2. #> git config --global user.email "tu correo"

Con eso ya tienes git configurado.

Para mostrar tus configuraciones ejecuta:

```
git config --list
```

Deberia de salir algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ahora con git configurado necesitas de clonar el proyecto que esta en github.com**

Para eso te vas a la dirección del repositorio y copias la url del repo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora dentro de git ejecutas el comando "git clone "

```
git clone https://github.com/alcarazolabs/apktool.git
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y listo ya tendrías el proyecto en repositorio local:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora voy a crear un archivo llamado "index.html" y lo subiremos al repositorio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que puedas hacer el "git add xarhivo.." tienes que estar dentro de la carpeta del repositorio clonado".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces en el programa "git" haces:

```
git add index.html
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que necesitas hacer es un "commit":

```
git commit -m "comentario x sobre tu archivo"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora solo resta subir los archivos al repositorio remoto. Para ver los logs y commits ejecuta:

```
git log
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero antes de subir los cambios como estan trabajando en equipo necesitas de asegurarte de descargar el codigo actualizado del proyecto para eso ejecutas:

```
git pull origin main
```

Digo rama "main" que es la rama principal del proyecto, antes en github las ramas principales se llamaban "master". Para sacarte de la duda de cual es la rama principal de trabajo o del proyecto ejecuta "git branch" esto debe de arrojarte todas las ramas del repositorio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces en este caso el proyecto tiene una unica rama principal, por lo tanto te descargas el codigo actualizado antes de subir el codigo del commit que has realizado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Subimos el archivo al repo remoto:

```
git push origin main
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora si revisamos el repositorio en github debe de aparecer el ultimo archivo agregado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno esto es básicamente esto es un ejemplo de como clonar y subir archivos a un repositorio github. Te recomiendo que leas sobre ramas o branch en git y como crearlas y usarlas. Averigua otros comandos sobre como eliminar commits, modificarlos etc.. por ultimo te recomiendo que uses visual studio code ahi veras que cuando modificas un archivo siendo este proyecto un repositorio git te marcara con un color el archivo modificado y cuando le hagas commit desaparecera ese color. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @Freddy Daniel excelente! muchas gracias por tu explicación. Pude encontrar un video tutorial que me sirvió para logralo.

Comment: Excelente @Claudio sigue asi.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes simplemente poner esto en el gitbash:
`git remote -v`

Y te dirá el la url del repositorio en el que te encuentras.
Si deseas más información sobre cómo funciona GitHub, [este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWglK8nWh60) parece ser el mejor que se encuentra en Google.

Éxitos y bendiciones.